# compare the values of two array for change log

Tags: php, arrays

I searched and tried many solutions from Google like `array_diff`, `array_intersect` and `array_map` but somehow I am unable to get the result that I am looking for.

Let me share some of the examples and what I want.

**It's on Edit User Page:**

**Section A:**
Previously admin had selected `$regions=[5,6,2]`for this user
and now admin selects `$regions=[2,6,7]`

I want to send out an email that there is a change in your regions list previous regions and these are the new regions if there is a change!

**Section B:**
if there is no change like below then no email

```
`$regions_old=[5,6,2]`
`$regions_new=[2,6,5]`
```

**Section C:**

`$regions_old=[5]`
`$regions_new=[2,6,5]`

**Section D:**

`$regions_old=[2,5,6]`
   `$regions_new=[2]`

I need two arrays with old regions and new regions list if there is any change. I tried counting both arrays but in that case, `Section B` Failed.

any help please

Comment: I don't understand why `array_diff` is not a suitable solution for what you want to achieve..

Comment: It doesn't returns me values 2 and 6 and fails on section c. When i do this print_r(array_diff($regions_old, $regions_new));

Comment: have you checked whether the answer solves your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have two arrays `$regions_old` and `$regions_new` you can get what you want by creating two variables that take advantage of `array_diff` to determine the changes in the arrays.

More specifically:

`$regions_added = array_diff($regions_new, $regions_old);`

`$regions_removed = array_diff($regions_old, $regions_new);`

The following scenarios can be used to test the logic above:

**case 1: Regions are the same**

`$regions_old = [5, 6, 2];`

`$regions_new = [2, 6, 5];`

Both `$regions_added` and `$regions_removed` are going to return empty arrays in this case, so no changes have been made.

**case 2: Regions have been added**

`$regions_old = [5];`

`$regions_new = [2, 6, 5];`

`$regions_added` is going to return an array with two elements `[2, 6]` whereas `$regions_removed` is going to return an empty array. This means, that the user added two extra regions to the already existing `$regions_old`.

**case 3: Regions have been removed**

`$regions_old = [2, 5, 6];`

`$regions_new = [2];`

`$regions_added` is going to return an empty array whereas `$regions_removed` is going to return an array with two elements `[5, 6]`. This means, that the user removed two regions from the already existing `$regions_old`.

**case 4: Regions have completely changed**

`$regions_old = [2, 5, 6];`

`$regions_new = [4, 1, 3];`

`$regions_added` is going to return an array with three elements `[4, 1, 3]` and `$regions_removed` is going to return an array with three elements `[2, 5, 6]`. This means, that the user completely changed the regions.

Comment: I up voted it. It makes sense. Let me try this solution